# For google analytics i am getting Status: Tracking Not Installed

Tags: javascript, search, google-analytics, seo, google-analytics-api

I have added Google analytics to my site

http://share-books.herokuapp.com/

when i view page source, google analytics scripts is there, but i am getting the following message when i view the statistics, and there are 0 visits. Can any one kindly help me what is the problem.

```
Status: Tracking Not Installed
```

In Google analytic console, i am getting the following

```
Initializing Google Analytics. analytics_debug.js:9
Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "linker", Function) analytics_debug.js:9
Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "displayfeatures", Function) analytics_debug.js:9
Running command: ga(create, UA-49998516-1, share-books.herokuapp.com) analytics_debug.js:9
Creating new tracker: t0 analytics_debug.js:9
Running command: ga(send, pageview) analytics_debug.js:9

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j18d&a=647141557&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fshare-books.herokuapp.com%2F&dr=http%3A%2F%2Fshare-books.tk%2F&ul=en-us&de=ISO-8859-1&dt=Share-Book%20%3A%20Donate%20your%20extra%20books&sd=24-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=1302x656&je=1&fl=12.0%20r0&_u=MCC~&cid=1568974250.1397466959&tid=UA-49998516-1&z=1432730148
```

Can anyone kindly help me. I have search a lot over the internet and tried different ways like deleting scrip. But no luck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: @JohnConde Google Analytics questions are not off-topic there's a tag sponsored by Google for these questions.  I have probably answered 20 questions relating to the Tracking code.

Comment: Your tracking code looks good to me. Did you check the Real-time reports.  Data in the standard reports can take up to 24-48 hours to show up.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks, it started working after some time, today when i check it, it was working as expected. thank you for reply

Answer (score 1):

I think you have enabled Universal Analytics but you have not replaced Analytics tracking code.